# Is there a way to pass a URL to options in rmarkdown header?

Tags: css, r-markdown

My team has used custom css and html documents to generate branded reports from rmarkdown documents. Within our team we have a shared file structure, and so we've been using absolute paths to the style documents that allow us to just copy the report documents themselves into new folders and successfully knit. E.g.:

```
title: Example report header
subtitle: "`r params$study_name`"
author: "`r params$author_name`"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    css: /absolute/path/to/css/style.css
    highlight: null
    includes:
      in_header: /absolute/path/to/header/header.html
```

We're interested in sharing these `.Rmd` files with some collaborators, but we aren't able to give them access to our shared file structure. Ideally, we'd like to be able to share with the same convenience that our team has been able to enjoy, where they would only need to create copies of the `.Rmd` files and not the style documents.

The best approach I've been able to think of to achieve this goal is to host these style documents on a public URL, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on whether passing URLs into the header would work with native `rmarkdown`, nor any tools that purport to make this possible.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```yaml
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: null
    includes:
      in_header: styles.html
```

and in **styles.html**:

```html
<link href="your_hosted_styles_file.css" rel="stylesheet">
```